# Calling While loop Function in __main__?

Tags: python, function, while-loop, python-multithreading

Here I have a program which polls the queue for an event, if found it executes an order to a REST API.  In addition if an event is found, it prints the current price that I need to use as my `stopLoss`.  This code runs exactly as I would like it to, however, the moment I try and call the function `rates()` inside the `__main__` the program just stops running.

Remove the reference `stopLoss = rates()` and the program runs great just without a `stopLoss`, but I need the rate `-.001` as my `stopLoss`.

Code as follows:

```
import Queue
import threading
import time
import json
import oandapy

from execution import Execution
from settings import STREAM_DOMAIN, API_DOMAIN, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCOUNT_ID
from strategy import TestRandomStrategy
from streaming import StreamingForexPrices

#polls API for Current Price
def stop():
        while True:
            oanda = oandapy.API(environment="practice", access_token="xxxxxx")
            response = oanda.get_prices(instruments="EUR_USD")
            prices = response.get("prices")
            asking_price = prices[0].get("ask")
            s = asking_price - .001
            return s

#Checks for events and executes order                
def trade(events, strategy, execution):
    while True:
        try:
            event = events.get(False)
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
        else:
            if event is not None:
                if event.type == 'TICK':
                    strategy.calculate_signals(event)
                elif event.type == 'ORDER':
                    print 
                    execution.execute_order(event)

def rates(events):
            while True:
                try:
                    event = events.get(False)
                except Queue.Empty:
                    pass
                else:
                        if event.type == 'TICK':
                                r = stop()
                                print r

if __name__ == "__main__":
    heartbeat = 0  # Half a second between polling
    events = Queue.Queue()

# Trade 1 unit of EUR/USD
    instrument = "EUR_USD"
    units = 1
    stopLoss = rates()  #Problem area!!!!!!>>>>>>>>>>>>>>//////////////////////////

    prices = StreamingForexPrices(
        STREAM_DOMAIN, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCOUNT_ID,
        instrument, events
    )
    execution = Execution(API_DOMAIN, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCOUNT_ID)

    strategy = TestRandomStrategy(instrument, units, events, stopLoss)


#Threads
    trade_thread = threading.Thread(target=trade, args=(events, strategy, execution))
    price_thread = threading.Thread(target=prices.stream_to_queue, args=[])
    stop_thread = threading.Thread(target=rates, args=(events,))      

# Start both threads
    trade_thread.start()
    price_thread.start()
    stop_thread.start()
```

Comment: Are you sure, you don't get any exception? From what I see your `stopLoss = rates()` line should raise a `TypeError` since you do not provide the `events` argument... you probably want to remove the parentheses to get a reference to the method, rather than calling it ;)

Comment: Yes you are right, I do get a error "Received request with malformed body: 'units=1&instrument=EUR_USD&type=market&side=buy&stopLoss=%3Cfunction+rates+at+0x1040f9f50%3E'"..

Comment: and when I run it like this  'stopLoss = rates(events)' nothing at all happens..  It just won't run?

Comment: Yeah of course nothing happens, you have nobody to fill your queue while you're stuck in the loop within `rates`... I think your problem is, that you have not yet understood how threading works. Unfortunately I don't have enough time right now to explain it, but if later this evening you still don't have an answer I'll give it a go ;)

Comment: I agree, I have been lost for days and I am just now starting to see through the fog.  Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay no answers so far, so I'll try.
Your main problem seems to be, that you don't know how to interchange data between threads.
First the problem with the price.

The loop here:

```
while True:
    oanda = oandapy.API(environment="practice", access_token="xxxxxx")
    response = oanda.get_prices(instruments="EUR_USD")
    prices = response.get("prices")
    asking_price = prices[0].get("ask")
    s = asking_price - .001
    return s
```

Has no effect, because `return s` will automatically break out of it.
So what you need is a shared variable where you store `s`. You can protect the access to it by using `threading.Lock`. The easiest way would be to subclass Thread and make `s` an instance attribute like this (I named it `price`):

```
class PricePoller(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, interval):
        super(PricePoller, self).__init__()
        # private attribute, will be accessed as property via
        # threadsafe getter and setter
        self._price = None
        # lock guarding access to _price
        self._dataLock = threading.Lock()
        # polling interval
        self.interval = interval
        # set this thread as deamon, so it will be killed when
        # the main thread dies
        self.deamon = True
        # create an event that allows us to exit the mainloop
        # and terminate the thread safely
        self._stopEvent = threading.Event()

    def getPrice(self):
        # use _dataLock to get threadsafe access to self._price
        with self._dataLock:
            return self._price

    def setPrice(self, price)
        # use _dataLock to get threadsafe access to self._price
        with self._dataLock:
            self._price = price

    price = property(getPrice, setPrice, None)

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopEvent.isSet():
            oanda = oandapy.API(environment="practice", access_token="xxxxxx")
            response = oanda.get_prices(instruments="EUR_USD")
            prices = response.get("prices")
            asking_price = prices[0].get("ask")
            self.price = asking_price - .001
            time.sleep(self.interval) # don't spam the server

    def stop(self):
        self._stopEvent.set()
```

It can then be started with:

```
poller = PricePoller(heartbeat)
poller.start()
```

And you can get the price with `poller.price` wherever you want! You can even pass the poller on to other threads if you like.
BUT! If you try to get the price immediately after `poller.start()` you will certainly get a `None`. Why this? `poller.start()` does not block, therefore while your main thread is going on and tries to get the first price, your poller has not even finished starting!
How to solve this? Introduce another `threading.Event` and use its function `wait` to let the main thread wait until the poller thread has set it. I leave the implementation up to you.

I'm just guessing that this is what you want... looking only at your code you don't have to put the `stop` function in a thread **at all** and you can just replace `stopLess = rates()` with `stopLess = stop()`, because you're not updating the results from the price polling anywhere! But I think you want to do that at some point, otherwise it wouldn't make sense to put it into a thread.

Now to the queue and your 'event stream'.
This snippet:

```
try:
    event = events.get(False)
except Queue.Empty:
    pass
```

Can just as well be:

```
event = events.get()
```

You're doing nothing in the meantime anyway and it is better to let `Queue` deal with waiting for an event.
Then, as far as I can see, you have two threads calling `Queue.get`, but this function will delete the element from the queue after retrieving it! This means whoever obtains the event first, consumes it and the other thread will never see it. But with the above solution for the poller, I think you can get rid of the `stop_thread`, which also solves that problem.

Now a note on Threads in general.
A thread has its own 'chain' of calls that starts within its `run` method (or the method which you supply as `target` if you don't subclass).
That means whatever function is called by `run` is executed by this thread, and also all functions that are called in turn by this one (and so on). HOWEVER, it is perfectly possible that two threads execute the same function, at the same time! And there is no way to know which thread executes which part of the code at a certain time, if you do not use means of synchronisation (e.g. Events, Locks or Barriers). 
This is no problem if all variables used in a called function are local ore were local in the calling function:

```
def onlyLocal(x, n):
    if n == 0:
        return x
    return onlyLocal(x*2, n-1)
```

or are exclusively read:

```
def onlyRead(myarray):
    t = time.time()
    return t - sum(myarray)
```

But as soon as you do both read from and write to a variable from multiple threads, you need to secure access to those because otherwise if you pass objects which are known by more than one thread (for example `self`):

```
def setPrice(self, price):
    self._price = price
```

or if your function uses variables from an outer scope which is acessed by multiple threads:

```
def variableFromOutside(y):
    global x
    x += y
    return y
```

You can never be sure that there isn't a thread(2) changing a variable which you(1) have just read, while you are processing it and before you update it with a then invalid value.

```
global x ; Thread1 ;  Thread2 ;
    2    ;  y = x  ;   z = x  ;
    2    ; y **= 3 ;  x = z+1 ;
    3    ; x = y-4 ;   return ;
    4    ;  return ;   ...    ;
```

This is why you have to secure the access to those variables with locks.  With a Lock (`l`):

```
global x ;    Thread1   ;   Thread2   ;
    2    ; l.acqcuire() ; l.acquire() ;
    2    ; y = x        ;      |      ;
    2    ; y **= 3      ;      |      ;
    2    ; x = y-4      ;      |      ;
    4    ; l.release()  ;      v      ;
    4    ; return       ; z = x       ;
    4    ; ...          ; x = z+1     ;
    5    ; ...          ; l.release() ;
```

Here Thread1 acquires the lock before Thread2. Thread2 therefore has to wait until Thread1 releases the lock again before its call to `acquire` returns.
`acquire` and `release` are automatically called when you use `with lock:`.
Note also that in this toy example it could have been the case that Thread2 aqcuires the lock before Thread1, but at least they would still not interfere with each other.

This was a brief introduction on a large topic, read a bit about thread parallelisation and play around with it. There is no better means for learning than practice.
*I've written this code here in the browser and therefore it is **not** tested! If someone finds issues, please tell me so in the comments or feel free to change it directly.*

Comment: WOW!  A thousand thank yous swenzel!  I very much appreciate the answer!